# How to get iOS style components in react native

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm making a notes app and currently I have done my own styling for things such as the FlatList. How can I make the components resemble real iOS components such as the list in the notes app for iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by creating a native wrapper for the component. You can try to find maybe somebody who already created it on GitHub or implement it yourself following this guide https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.69/native-components-ios.

If you decide to build it yourself you can use this CLI https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob which will generate template.